# Nokogiri not found in any sources even though install in gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, passenger

When I try to access by ruby on rails app, served by passenger on a CentOS server, I get the following error:

```
Could not find nokogiri-1.8.5 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

Despite the fact that when `bundle install` is run, the output `Using nokogiri 1.8.5` is shown.

I've removed the Gemfile.lock file and run `gem install bundle`, I've overwritten the cache.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using rvm?

Comment: Yes, I am using rvm

Comment: Can you ensure that you are using the intended rails version in RVM? For `rvm list` and then `rvm use X.X.X` then run bundle install again.